# Temporary network outage when Symantec Endpoint Network protection is enabled

Tags: ping, endpoint

I got a new laptop with Windows 7 some time ago. Since that time I have observed that network traffic is slower. When I ping my local gateway I got following ping times:?

```
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=57ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=57ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=57ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=3024ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=57ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=57ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=57ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=57ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
```

Especially arguing is the ping of 3024ms or Request timed out as it means that there is a short network outage. As a consequence I have a drop when I am using software phone.

When I disable Network Endpoint proection my pings to the gateway are OK:

```
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
```

This happens in all locations for my computer and the computers for my colleagues who use the same Symantec Endpoint Protection version (12.1.4013.4013)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it was the issue with policies fetched from policy server. Clicking **Update policy** button after right click on on Symantec icon in tray resolved it.